# What do you call a one-sided cleat?

Tags: hanging

I’d like to use something like the rope cleat below to hang something from a wall. However, I don’t need the other side of the cleat. Is there such a thing as a one-sided cleat? What do you call it?

[image]

Comment: Wander thru some place that sells parts for sailboats (or boats in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a "wall hook", sometimes described as "low profile", "flat", or "angled". You're more likely to see them as sheet metal bars than rods.

A "halyard cleat" or "jam cleat" is similar, but they tend to be higher profile.

I'd take a hacksaw to that one. It's not like they're expensive. Or buy a simple angle bracket and flatten it somewhat.

Comment: If you cut it, don't cut it in the middle....leave two holes.  One hole could allow the hook to swivel.

Answer (score 0):

A **coat hook** would be an alternate version, though they usually have both a larger and smaller hook for hanging things (your coat and hat, of course.) But one-hook versions are sold.

Also trivial to make your own from wood, in the format you want.

Comment: If you do make it from wood, run the grain vertically or it'll break first time out.

Answer (score 0):

Found a wooden one at [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/nz/listing/848728700/wooden-hook-nautical-style-half-cleat)

There's a brass one called "[single hook](https://www.diy.com/departments/b-q-zinc-alloy-single-hook-holds-3kg/243585_BQ.prd)" which may not be exactly what you want.

Then there's the [linemate](http://www.monarchproducts.com/linemate.htm)  which looks exactly like what you want but perhaps too rugged.   Might be worth Google-Shopping for "linemate."